# Reusing variable in Rails model methods for improved load time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to reuse a collection of data in a Rails model to speed up load times.

```
class MyKlass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  def init
    @first_thing = big_data_set
    @second_thing = another_big_data_set
    @third_thing = yet_another_big_data_set
  end

  def one_method
    a = @first_thing.do_something(x).count
    b = @second_thing.do_something(x).count
    total = a+b
  end

  def another_method
    a = @first_thing.do_something(x).count
    b = @second_thing.do_something(x).count
    c = @third_thing.do_something(x).count
    total = a+b+c
  end

end
```

This makes my loading times pretty big since it seems it keeps running back and reloading the data, I've tried using constants but those aren't a good solution since the data may change on page refresh. What I'm looking for it to do is to load once, then reuse that same variable for one_method and another_method since I can use the same pre-loaded dataset for both methods.

Edit:

I should also mention I'm iterating over a large dataset that calls on these methods:

```
Model.all.each do |x|
  x.one_method
  x.another_method
end
```

I noticed if I make them into class methods without the init, then it loads substantially faster and it looks like it's doing much less "running back and forth", though I read that is a poor way of solving this issue:

```
class MyKlass < ActiveRecord::Base

  @@first_thing = big_data_set
  @@second_thing = another_big_data_set
  @@third_thing = yet_another_big_data_set

  def one_method
    a = @@first_thing.do_something.count
    b = @@second_thing.do_something.count
    total = a+b
  end

end
```

Comment: You want to reuse a,b,c? b/c \@first_thing, \@second_thing are member variables and already cached.

Comment: @Rob please see my edited answer - that's also what I had thought but then I realized storing them as class variables @@ it did a lot less running back and forth which made me think that it's running that method every time it iterates over Model.all

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given example, I see no reason at all why this code even exists in the `MyKlass` model. Instance methods of an ActiveRecord model should be directly applicable to the row in the table the model is representative of.

This looks like it should be a plain service object.

```
class DataSet
  attr_reader :first, :second, :third

  def initialize(first, second, third)
    @first  = first
    @second = second
    @third  = third
  end

  def first_count
    @first_count ||= first.do_something.count
  end

  def second_count
    @second_count ||= second.do_something.count
  end

  def third_count
    @third_count ||= third.do_something.count
  end

  def total
    first_count + second_count + third_count
  end
end
```

Initialize this once and [use memoization](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/) to prevent repeated calls to the same long-running processes.

Comment: The .count was just a simplified example, it collects a large dataset of the model at the point in time which the page is accessed, and then should change with refresh (if there were updates).

So the initialize would have something like:

dataset1 = MyHelper.gather_data.do_stuff_with_data 
dataset2 = MyHelper.gather_more_data.do_stuff_with_data

And then the methods would have to use the dataset1 and dataset2 which is called in every iteration of Model.all.each

I hope that makes more sense

Comment: @asalgan a simplified example is fine, but I think you are leaving out important information about your data model that prevents me from answering your question. I still don't see how these large datasets relate to the specific row your model is representing.

Comment: So this pertains to a join table of a Product model, ProductSet, so the large data set gathers a collection of ProductSets with a certain set of attributes, and another dataset of ProductSet with a different set of attributes. A ProductSet has many products (& multiples of the same) so what I'm trying to do is iterate over Products, calling one_method, another_method, etc. on every Product (this is for admins so it goes over each product). Since dataset1 and dataset2 don't change, I don't want it to collect dataset1 and dataset2 with every Product iteration. I hope that makes more sense

Comment: If you declare the relationship to the Product and ProductSet, something like maybe <<has_many :products>>, then Rails associations would automatically cache the objects. And you can walk through the results of an activerecord relation using "find_in_batches" if you have a large data set. So I would recommend exploring associations in rails. Equally, you can cache large results that don't change over time using the rails cache. The advantage there being that the rails cache allows the operations team to pick the best cache service for the final deployment

Comment: @Rob true only if the large datasets are 1, coming from ActiveRecord and 2, related to `MyKlass` in some way. In that case I agree with you that using the relations would be best, but the question as posed does not give me enough information to assume that.

Comment: @asalgan okay so you have multiple collections of `ProductSet` that are selected according to differing criteria. You are iterating over a set of `Product`s and based on the state of each `Product`, you are making alterations to the `ProductSet` collections, and currently you are generating the collections separately for each `Product`. Is that correct?

Comment: @AdamLassek yeah, I agree with you. However, he did derive from ActiveRecord, so I assumed he simply didn't understand how ActiveRelations worked.